# Разделить данные одного столбца на несколько по условию

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прописать запрос.
Есть выборка из двух таблиц вот в таком виде :
[image: как есть]

Нужно чтобы выводилась информация  вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используется MS SQL Server 2017
Заранее очень благодарен

Comment: Да вульгарный же PIVOT. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: Спасибо! А то натыкался на Case и не получалось